# use Invoke-Command to start a process but failed with no action

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, start-process

I need to install some application on a list of machines. on one of machines, i use below command to install it, it works well and finish installation in a few mins.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\javabits.exe" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait
```

However when I use `Invoke-Command` to push it to a list of machines, it finishes immediately without error message, and the application wasn't installed. May I know why this happens?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist -ScriptBlock {
    Start-Process -FilePath "c:\javabits.exe" -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait
}
```

Comment: Do you start the `invoke-command` with the adequate credentials on the remote computer?

Comment: yes. using my credential which is administrator on these machines.

Comment: Is it working if you specify one hostname instead of a list?

Comment: there should be some setting on these machines which caused this issue, since i can push this command to other machine list. specify one is also not work. do you know which setting will impact this?

Comment: what happens when you create a file instead of starting an application? e.g. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverlist -ScriptBlock {"test" | Out-File c:\test.txt"}` is it created?